# How to send soap request through Android?

Tags: android, soap, android-ksoap2

How can I send a request to this service?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <total xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <validationRequest>
        <Name>string</Name>
        <num1>int</num1>
        <num2>int</num2>
      </validationRequest>
    </total>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Android code:

```
private static final String NAMESPACE ="http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION ="http://tempuri.org/total";
private static final String URL ="http://10.0.2.2:1743/Service1.asmx";
private TextView tv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setText(ws());
}

private String ws() {
    String result = "";
    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);    
        System.out.println("ohaissxh");
        PropertyInfo quotesProperty = new PropertyInfo();

        request.addProperty("Name","Nas");
        request.addProperty("num1",6);
        request.addProperty("num2",5);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        System.out.println("dfdjsssf");

        if(envelope.getResponse()!=null){
            //SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
            Object response = envelope.getResponse();
            result = response.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = e.getMessage();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your SOAP request,
**`<validationRequest>`** is a complex request type and you simply cannot add the property in the `request`, as usually done for primitive types.

You need to **create a class** which **`extends Vector`** and **`implements KVMSerializable`**.

```
public class ValidationReq extends Vector<String> implements KvmSerializable {


        @Override
        public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
                return this.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public int getPropertyCount() {
                return this.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void getPropertyInfo(int arg0, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo arg2) {
                arg2.name = "string";
                arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        }

        @Override
        public void setProperty(int arg0, Object arg1) {
                this.add(arg1.toString());
        }

}
```

Your class would contain the parameters that you want to send and you need to add the object of the class to the `request`.

Sample code snippet can be found in the [**official KSOAP documentation**](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#sending/receiving_array_of_complex_types_or_primitives).